# Autoresize ImageButton with LayerDrawable background

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton, autoresize, text-size

I have an ImageButton, which should contain the text.
For this I use LayerDrawable (createImage method in CustomViewFactory class)
In short

```
 public class CustomViewFactory extends ImageButton {
    public CustomViewFactory createButton(String text) {
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(createImage(R.drawable.back_configuration, text));
    return this;
    }
```

back_configuration.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_pressed" adroid:state_pressed="true">     </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_normal"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>

    </selector>
```

back_button_normal and back_button_pressed - 9 patch png files.

```
public LayerDrawable createImage(int resource, String text){
        Drawable [] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = new TextDrawable(text);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.back_configuration);
        return new LayerDrawable(resource);
    }

public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;
    public TextDrawable(String text) {

        this.text = text;
       this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true); 
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Problem. If the text is large, then it is cut off. How to make ImageButton itself increased in size depending on the text inside. What are the alternative methods.

And if I use the Button, the image is stretched on the button

I apologize for my English. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using textView rather than imageView or imageButton and then assign background for the text view as the image you want and set the text you want for textView and make it wrap_content for layout_width

**Edit:** check if you use padding for the text view remove it.

Comment: Thank you! It's really work. There was one problem. The text is not in the middle. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/26032627.png/

Comment: You can set gravity attribute for the textView to center

Comment: android:gravity="center" ... if the answer works for you you can tick it on the left

Comment: setGravity(center) for the textView not working. It's a fitst, what i try

Comment: Sorry, gravity work, but image and text does not match. I set 10 lines. See http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/53823453.png/

Comment: Not at all ... so now what is the status? is it still like the image in the link?

Comment: Yes( If i use setText method, text and image don't match...they use different "center's".

Comment: wrap_content for width and height

Comment: No effect's. I want to get component (view) with: scaling, image, text. Button stretching image. ImageButton has no setText method. TextView very good stretching image depending on text, but text and image don't match...ideas?

Comment: I don't know why, but when i change source class (replace "extends TextView" on "extends Button"), nothing change's. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/32/34392910.png/ . I try and TextView, and Button. No differences

Comment: Amt87, thank you very much. It's was my mistake. I use 9 patch incorrectly, forget set content pathes.